# password field background changes after using iscroll

Tags: cordova, iscroll4

I have implemented iscroll in login page,actually my password field has brown background color,when focus on password field to type text the background vanished and came white background.Could any one suggest the solution for this issue.

This is the code:

```
input[type="text"],input[type="password"], input[type="email"]
{
  height: 40px;   width: 200px;   -moz-border-radius:5px; -webkit-border-radius:5px; border-radius: 5px;
}

#wrapper
{
  position:absolute; z-index:1; top:13%; bottom:10%; left:0; width:100%; overflow:auto;
}

#scroller
{
  position:absolute; z-index:1; /*-webkit-touch-callout:none;*/ -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); width:100%; padding:0%;
}

<form name="login" id="login_form">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="login_container">
      <div id="email_input">
        <input type='text' id='email' class='not_capital' placeholder='Email' autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off"/>
      </div>

      <div id="password_input">
        <input type='password' id='password' placeholder='Password' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <input type="submit" class="small_button" value="Login" id="login" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post some code of yours?

Comment: input[type="text"],input[type="password"], input[type="email"]
{
 height: 40px; 
 width: 200px; 
 -moz-border-radius:5px;
 -webkit-border-radius:5px;
  border-radius: 5px;

}

#wrapper {
 position:absolute; z-index:1;
 top:13%; bottom:10%; left:0;
 width:100%;
 
 overflow:auto;
}

#scroller {
 position:absolute; z-index:1;
 /*-webkit-touch-callout:none;*/
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
 width:100%;
 padding:0%;
}

Comment: <form name="login" id="login_form">
 <div class="row">
  <div id="login_container">
   <div id="email_input">
    <input type='text' id='email' class='not_capital' placeholder='Email' autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off"/>
   </div>
   <div id="password_input">
    <input type='password' id='password' placeholder='Password' />
   </div>
  
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="row">
 <input type="submit" class="small_button" value="Login" id="login" /> 
</div>

</form>

Comment: Next time you can edit your question and put those code on the question, so your question would become clear

Comment: @kolonel peteruk,is it perfect now?

Comment: So, about your case, I think the real problem was your input background that changed color on focus right? Have you done tried [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397911/jquery-background-color-change-on-focus-and-blur)?