# Changing the background colour of an active input selector

Tags: html, css, input, submit

Any reason why when I run this code,

```
input[type=submit]:active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

when I click the desired button it only flashes green for a split second and then returns to the original colour? How can I keep it permanently green?

Comment: With Javascript. Apply a class when its clicked. `:active` is doing exactly what it's supposed to. It only applies when the mouse button is held down.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:focus is what you want

Comment: Because the `active` state lasts only for a split second. Use JS and change the css on click

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:focus - **English version**

Comment: Oh, and `:focus` will only apply until you click on something else.

Comment: I had already tried focus but on the wrong selector so had assumed that wouldn't work, how dumb :(!

Comment: Oh, thanks @Paulie_D, my fault. Thanks for linking the en version. I guess focus is what he intended to use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397911/jquery-background-color-change-on-focus-and-blur

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
input[type=submit]:focus {
    background-color: green;
}
```

try this

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: but notice that when user focus out (eg. click outside) focus selector will be gone and default color will be back. If you want that permament you should create class for background-color and add it onclick with js. You can add attr to input `onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#000'"` if you not familiar with js

Comment: can you explain that a bit more as that is my next question..I am using reactjs with this

Comment: `<input type="submit" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = '#000'">` it should be fine with react, because it is pure js solution

Comment: there not a better way? I already have a method called on the onClick function

Comment: `yourMethod(event) {
      event.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
  }`

and in your render method 

`<input type="submit" onClick={this.yourMethod.bind(this)}>`

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You also need to use the `:focus` selector.

This then adds the background color to the input as it is the focused element.

```css
input[type=submit]:active, input[type=submit]:focus {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" />
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that `:focus` is not **permanent**. It only lasts until something else is clicked on.

Comment: @Paulie_D I would hope the explanation that it adds it to the *focused* element would be understandable